# Error when knitting Rmarkdown using cv template of vitae package

Tags: r, r-markdown

I installed and loaded package "vitae" for making CV in rmarkdown.

I open R, go to rmarkdown, templates and chose Curriculum Vitae (Awesome-CV format). I name the document and on clicking "OK", an rmarkdown document appears showing cv of Marie Curie. When I knit it, I get the following error:

```
Error in enc2utf8(text) : argument is not a character vector
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> writeLines.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, solved by force updating every package in my R installation.